# Threads in python dont be executed at the same time using urllib2

Tags: python, multithreading, urllib2

Hello I'm trying to execute 2 threads in python. These threads make urllib2 requests that run php files on different domains, but when i do it, only one of them runs. How can i have both of them running?. Thanks

```
import urllib2, threading
archivin=open("data.txt","r")


class hilo(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self): 
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        for x in archivin.readlines():
            try:
                url=urllib2.urlopen("http://www.mysite1.com/utils.php?data="+x.split(", ")[1])
            except:
                continue


class hilo2(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        for x in archivin.readlines():
            try:
                url2=urllib2.urlopen("http://www.mysite2.com/utils.php?data="+x.split(", ")[1])
            except:
                continue


mi_hilo1=hilo()
mi_hilo1.start()
mi_hilo2=hilo2()
mi_hilo2.start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the problem is with the Threads themselves.

You're reading all the lines of the same `archivin` file in two spots without "rewinding" it.

This is what happens in my computer if I try to read a file twice.

```
>>> f=open("virtuoso_hX2016.ini", 'r')
>>> f.tell()
0
>>> 
>>> [x for x in f.readlines()]
['[Database]\n',   
 'DatabaseFile='MaxDirtyBuffers=1333\n', 'SchedulerInterval=5\n', 
 'FreeTextBatchSize=1000\n', 'CheckpointInterval=10\n', 
 [ . . . ]
 'MinAutoCheckpointSize=200000\n', '\n', '[I18N]\n', 'XAnyNormalization=3\n']
>>> f.tell()
981
>>> [x for x in f.readlines()]
[]
```

If you see, the second `readlines` returns an empty list. That's because the first read set the `virtuoso_hX2016` file offset to the end of the file (it "consumed" it all). Also, see the first `tell()` call? It says `0` because the file offset is *"pointing"* to the beginning of the file. Once the file is read, the second `tell()` says `981` because it's pointing to the end of the file (the first read "consumed" all the file)

See this [seek](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_seek.htm) and [tell](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_tell.htm) methods tutorial.

In your particular case, I'd recommend (if the file is of a reasonably small size) reading the file contents before starting your threads and pass the contents as a parameter or do the file opening/reading within each thread's `run` method.

Comment: Thank you very much yeah was a problem with no rewind the pointer of the file. ilove you men :D